# I can't break down this sentence "The rules capture practices generally held to be beneficial"

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is full of the sentence (from Effective Java, by Joshua Bloch):

> The rules capture practices generally held to be beneficial by the best and most experienced programmers.

I can't break down `The rules capture practices generally held to be beneficial`. So I can't understand.

Comment: Does “practices *that are* generally” make more sense to you?

Comment: is `The rules capture practices generally` a noun phrase? or `capture` is a verb, and `practices (that are) generally` is a noun?

Comment: ***held** = **claimed, thought, believed***. Top programmers agree those are ***good*** practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a very simply structured sentence, except that the object is a bit long and unwieldy and elides a couple of words.

Subject: The rules

Verb: capture

Object: practices [that are] generally held to be beneficial by the best and most experienced programmers

Comment: Also "capture" can be a noun and "practices" can be a verb, but then the sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user253751 “Practices” can’t be a verb in UK English — that would be “practises”.